# MATLAB regexpi returns only one match

Tags: regex, matlab

I want to extract the numbers enveloped in 't' tags. I have used the following commands in MATLAB:

```
str ='<t abc>1.3</t><t efg>32.3</t>';
[tokens] = regexpi(str,  '<t.*>(\d*\.\d*)</t>', 'tokens');
celldisp(tokens)
```

The output only shows the last match 32.3. I'm not sure why regexpi is returning only the last match?

Comment: the expression: `<t.*?>(\d*\.\d*)</t>` works. This to me is confusing as your expression for the first tag is greedy and returns only the first match, where mine is lazy and returns both matches...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To capture what you need, you should use this pattern: `<t.*?>(.*?)<\/t>`

```
str ='<t abc>1.3</t><t efg>32.3</t>';
[tokens] = regexpi(str,  '<t.*?>(.*?)<\/t>', 'tokens')
celldisp(tokens)
```

The result is what you are looking for:

```
tokens{1}{1} =

1.3

tokens{2}{1} =

32.3
```

Comment: Can you please explain why your solution is working? What is wrong with my understanding and code? Thanks.

Comment: @zander The expression is incorrect as you are not matching digits only. @ubaabd asked for numbers in the tag. For input `str ='<t abc>12.3a</t><t efg>32ab.3</t>'` it returns `{'12.3a'}` and `{'32ab.3'}`

Comment: @pkpkpk run the second `regexpi` on it to get what you need.

Comment: @ubaabd There is nothing wrong with your pattern. For some reason in MATLAB, this combination often gives you the last match rather than all matches.

Comment: @Zander I was referring to the expression you posted